# Java11でライブラリが読み込めません。

Tags: java, macos

mac(Mojave)を使っています。
jarファイルは`/Library/Java/Extensions/`に置けば読み込まれるという記事*を見かけたのですが、読み込まれません。

`/Library/Java/Extensions/`が参照されるようにするにはどうすればいいですか。

#### 追記

*の記事
http://kuwwta.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/05/12/184608
https://biojava.org/wiki/BioJava%3AGetStarted

JDKはOracleのホームページからdmgを使ってインストールしました。

Answer (score 2):

${JAVA_HOME/ext配下を拡張クラスローダに載せられるのはJava 8までの仕様です。
MACではjava.ext.dirsシステムプロパティあたりを利用して/Library/Java/Extensions/に変更しているのでしょうか？→他サイトも含めて古い記述のようですので、拡張クラスローダのことだと理解。

JAVA 9ではモジュールシステムの導入にあわせて、廃止されていますのでここにJARファイルを置いたからといってクラスローダにのりません。環境変数CLASSPATHに乗せておくか起動時に-cpを利用して指定してください。依存関係もまとめて設定するのなら、maven/gradelなどを利用すると楽です。

詳細は以下を参照ください。
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/9/migrate/toc.htm

Comment: そうだったんですね。よく分かりました。ありがとうございます！！